# Identification of fungus like fuzz on apple tree

Tags: identification, apples, fungus

This is an apple tree in western Germany that recently began to show some white fuzz on a couple of snags on the tree. Can you identify this by the shown picture? [image: apple tree with white fuzz]

Does it any harm, shall I take any measures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends - is there anything resembling this on other parts of the tree, perhaps on the leafed branches? This could be woolly aphid, it could be scale eggs (some scale insects lay their eggs under white cottony threads like this), but if it was either of those, I'd expect to see further evidence on the rest of the tree. Otherwise, it could be some kind of fungal growth, and its presence at a wound site might be troublesome, though it depends how long ago this particular branch was removed. Also, any fungal growths on trees which suggest a serious rotting problem are usually of the bracket kind, totally different from this. Suggest you inspect as much of the tree as you can, including undersides of leaves, to see what's there.

Comment: I've looked at the tree but could only find these at the wound sites, nothing at the leaves. I now sprayed some soapy water with lavender oil at those places. Thanks!

Comment: I had an almost identical-looking fuzz on my young apple trees that turned out to be woolly aphids. To the OP: try smooshing it. Does it turn purple?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is either [Woolly Aphid](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=724) or [Scale Insects](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=224)